# ¿Como hacer un triangulo invertido en C#?

Tags: c#

tengo problema con un ejercicio en C# que es realizar un triangulo invertido, tanto de lado izquierdo como derecho y al momento de compilar me tira los datos en forma lineal o sin darle la forma que corresponde.

[image: El objetivo es que forme estas formas]

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int lado; 
        int i, j;
        char C;
    while (true)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("INGRESE UN NUMERO: ");
    lado = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if (lado >0 && lado < 10) break;

    }
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el asterisco: ");
        C = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

        for (i = 1; i <= lado; i+=1)
        {
          for (j = 1; j <= lado -i+1; j+=1)
          {
            Console.WriteLine(C);
          }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    
}
```

}

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: Puedes poner un ejemplo del resultado que esperas

Comment: Si Dark,el la imagen del objetivo esta a inicio.
Y lo siento Beta, soy nuevo y no sabia que habia hecho corrección.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No tengo idea para que puede servir este código, pero aquí lo tienes.
Bueno entiendo que sirve como un buen entrenamiento, es útil para darse cuenta que la lógica de programación, tiene que estar en función, de los objetivos que se persiguen.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
int lado; 
        int i, j;
        char C;
    while (true)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("INGRESE UN NUMERO: ");
    lado = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if (lado >0 && lado < 10) break;

    }
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el asterisco: ");
        C = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

        for (i = 1; i <= lado; i++)
        {
          //creamos la cadena de asteriscos
          string cc=C.ToString();
          for (j = 1; j <= lado -i+1; j++)
          {
            cc=cc+C.ToString();
          }
          //creamos la cadena de espacios en blanco
          string space="";
          for (j =  lado -i+1; j <= lado; j++)
          {
            space=space+"  ";
          }
          //Imprimimos por pantalla cadena de asteriscos + espacios + asteriscos
          Console.WriteLine(cc+space+cc);
        }
        Console.ReadKey(); 
}
```

Comment: No queda claro que digas para que digas *para que puede servir* pues es tu respuesta amigo

Comment: @BetaM Tienes razon, se que por lo menos sirve como un buen entrenamiento.